# Jest testing mock functions __mocks__ TypeError: x is not a function

Tags: jestjs, typeerror

I have a class called call.js which has a toggleAudio function. I am trying to mock this function so I can use it in my tests. The code is as follows:

My test:

```
test('toggleAudio function', () => {
    toggleAudio = require('./call');
    jest.mock('./call')
    expect(toggleAudio(true)).toBe(true);
});
```

My mocked file inside **mocks**/call.js

```
function toggleAudio(b) {
    return b;
};
```

Getting error:

```
TypeError: toggleAudio is not a function

      13 |     toggleAudio = require('./call');
      14 |     jest.mock('./call')
    > 15 |     expect(toggleAudio()).toBe(true);
         |            ^
      16 | });
      17 |
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be giving it a parameter? If the parameter list is different, then most languages consider it to be a different method, so your error makes sense.

Comment: Are you exporting the `toggleAudio` function?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the extra white space between the function name and body..

```
function toggleAudio(b){
    return b;
};
```